# React useState Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I am confused as to why Iam getting this error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
It happens when I try and call useState to save the checkBoxList data.
If I comment out the line **setListOptions(checkBoxList);** the error goes away. What I expected to happen is that the setListoptions should be saved locally with  and then I can call the listOptions to map my data.
Thanks for the assistance.

```
const ZoneDashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const [listOptions, setListOptions] = useState<EnumMapping[]>();
  const classes = useStyles();

  const renderOptions = () => {
    if (!showOptions) return <div />;
    let checkBoxListLookup = enumHardwareValuesLookup(17375, attribs);
    let checkboxEnabled = enumHardwareValuesLookup(16513, attribs);
    let checkBoxList = new Array<EnumMapping>();

    checkBoxListLookup.forEach(function (key) {
      let enabled = checkboxEnabled.some(function (enable) {
        return enable === key;
      });

      if (enabled) {
        let enumMapping = new EnumMapping(key, true);
        checkBoxList.push(enumMapping);
      }
    });
    setListOptions(checkBoxList);
    
  };

  return (
    <div>
    {renderOptions()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ZoneDashboard
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time you render your component, you call renderOptions(). Everytime you call renderOptions, you set a state variable. Every time you set a state variable, React rerenders. There's your loop.

Comment: ok so if i want to data manipulation do i have to do useEffect=()=>{
//code here
},[showOptions]

Comment: What are you trying to render with renderOptions? There is no JSX returned from there.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to save the data to listOptions and then map it it to JSX element. 
I was able to it this way doing the useEffect